# Can't reproduce my (spacemacs) config

Tags: spacemacs, python, config

Two PCs, same version of manjaro on both, same emacs version, same spacemacs version/branch, same config file.

Problems with python mode and company:
On my second PC, autocomplete doesn't work correctly, sometimes it's just crushed with "max recursion deep" error. Also `company` is disabled by default, but on second PC it's enabled. Here also a lot of small differences and errors, which make my second emacs just unusable.

Don't know why it happens and how to fix.
My .spacemacs file: https://pastebin.pl/view/e3de7419
I tried spacemacs version 0.2, 0.3, master, develop.
Emacs 27.1
Manjaro Release: 20.2.1
Python libs (jedi, flake8) installed.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to provide additional info, for someone to be able to help you. Dunno what info might help, though. Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: Spacemacs just grabs the "latest" version of each of a metric ton of third-party packages, yes?  To be using the *same* config on different machines you need *all* of the elisp in your config to be the same.  You should copy the whole config between machines, or use version control, or something similar.

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to work with an old spacemacs develop branch commit -- either do as phils suggests and copy the code that spacemacs downloaded when that commit was current, or use the head of the develop branch.  As phils says, if you start from an old spacemacs checkout and let spacemacs download everything you'll have a mix of old spacemacs code and new MELPA code, which may not always go well.  They have been working for a long time on a way to pin versions more nicely for stable spacemacs releases, but it's still work in progress I believe